# turn page programmatically in UIPageViewController from another tab in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UITabBarController as root view controller.

In this UITabBarController, I have 2 tabs: tabA and tabB.

tabA is a general view controller, and tabB is a viewController with a Container View in which a pageViewcontroller C is embeded.

Now there is a button in tabA, I want to realize the effect that when I click this button, it will jump to tabB and show the second page in C, everytime when click the button, it will call the function:

```
func swipeToIndex(ToIndex: Int, completion: (()->Void)? = nil) {
    if self.currentPageIndex > 2 {
        return
    }
    if ToIndex < self.currentPageIndex {
        let toViewController = self.orderedViewControllers[ToIndex]
        self.setViewControllers([toViewController], direction: .reverse, animated: true, completion: {finish in
            self.currentPageIndex = ToIndex
            completion?()
        })
    }
    else if ToIndex > self.currentPageIndex {
        let toViewController = self.orderedViewControllers[ToIndex]
        self.setViewControllers([toViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: {finish in
            self.currentPageIndex = ToIndex
            completion?()
        })
    }
}
```

I can only realize it from the second time that I click the button. And the first time, it goes to the first page in C. I found it's something to do with the viewDidLoad(). when it calls the function swipeToIndex for the first time after

> **self.setViewControllers([toViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: {finish in
>               self.currentPageIndex = ToIndex
>               completion?()
>           })** 
>   it will call **viewDidLoad**, inside there sets the viewcontroller again like following:

```
if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
        setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                           direction: .forward,
                           animated: true,
                           completion: nil)
    }
```

I have no clue how to avoid this when the first time call **swipeToIndex**

Comment: So if you open the app, navigate to tabB (showing page controller) and then navigate back to tabA pressing the button will work correctly? (while pressing the button on tabA will no work before tabB was seen at least once)

Comment: @MaticOblak yes, if navigate to tabB and back to tabA, pressing the button will work correctly. But I need to realize the effect that clicking the button on tabA works even the tabB hasn't been seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to forward message a bit smarter and check if views have already been loaded.

In your page controller you should check if a view is loaded:

```
func swipeToIndex(ToIndex: Int, completion: (()->Void)? = nil) {
    guard isViewLoaded else {
        self.pageToSwipeTo = ToIndex
        return
    }
```

So you need to add

```
var pageToSwipeTo: Int? = nil
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` at the end try

```
if let pageToSwipeTo = pageToSwipeTo {
    self.pageToSwipeTo = nil
    self. swipeToIndex(pageToSwipeTo)
}
```

This is assuming the page view controller does already exist in your situation. This might actually not be true due to your hierarchy so you might need to forward the message even through the tab bar view controller... But try this procedure first.

Comment: It's really brilliant solution. but before calling **viewDidLoad**, it called also again

       `var pageToSwipeTo: Int? = nil`

so when called before 

    `if let pageToSwipeTo = pageToSwipeTo {
        self.pageToSwipeTo = nil
        self. swipeToIndex(pageToSwipeTo)
    }`

**pageToSwipeTo** become nil again

Comment: Does it make sense to make **pageToSwipeTo** global variable or save to userDefaults?

Comment: User defaults doesn’t make sense but in some rare cases (be very careful) you make a static variable for index and a static method scroll to index. Then add a weak static variable as loadedController. Then do all the sane on thise. I hope rest is ligical...

Comment: I tried to define `var pageToSwipeTo: Int? = nil`  as a global variable in my constant file. it works perfect. Compared with the method you mentioned, it's much more simple. do you think it's also a good way to realize the effect?